# Best way to work with hierarchal python data that needs to be aggregated at many levels

Tags: python, data-structures, hierarchical-data

I have a very complex data-set that I need to easily aggregate and work with values at multiple levels.

For example, assume I have data on population and crime rate for each city in the US. Each city should roll up to a state, so the state population is the SUM of each city within it, and the crime rate is the AVERAGE of the crime rates of each city below it. Then I need each state to roll up to the US overall, maintaining the same calculation logic.

What is the best data structure to accomplish complex aggregations of hierarchically organized data in python?

Ideally I would be able to select a node, and then using some method feed the node an argument on what data to aggregate, and the logic to aggregate it with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### two words

use pandas

link to tutorial
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html

Comment: I vouch for pandas. Excellent library.

Comment: Haven't resolved my specific problem with this yet, but it looks very promising. So upvote. Thanks!

Comment: you didn't provide any problem to solve.If you are having specific issue in code please post the code